# Typescript: How to declare custom Map and Array in a .d.ts file

Tags: typescript, generics, declaration

I want to create custom type declarations of the Map and Array classes in a .d.ts file as follows:

```js
//iter.d.ts

interface CustomMap<U, V>{
    get(key: U): V | undefined;
    set(key: U, val: V): void;
}
interface CustomArray<T>{
    length(): number;
}
```

But I would like to be able to do the following using only declarations in the .d.ts file:

```js
//test.ts

cArray = new CustomArray<number>(1,3,2,3);
cArray[0] = 2;
console.log(cArray[2]) // 2
for (const i of cArray) {
    console.log(i);
}

cMap = new CustomMap<string, string>(['1', 'a'],['3', 'b'],['2', 'ç'],['4', 'd']);
for (const [k, v] of cMap) {
    console.log(k + ':' + v);
}
```

What should I add to the CustomMap and CustomArray interfaces?
(the target is ES2015 or higher).

Comment: By "only declarations" you mean you don't want to implement them and you only want the TypeScript compiler to know enough about their types to compile successfully?  Like [this](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgMIFcDOYD2BbAWTgAcAeAVQBpkA1APmQG8AoZN5AcwjAAoBrCAE8AXMnIBKUTWQAfZOhAATCDFARFAblbtM3fkNFVkANzgAbKZJM5gm7WwDaAZUF4ARjjMA6YJChxcKABdHisAST84NzMICOgAnChSByMaILpmAF9mZQQzOCgUBBwQbDQsXEISURAIAHdkCmp6Hi82uFEU5qCHIPFkAF4GDGx8IjJUui1mUD94JHLRvABBKH9BUgAVBhZ2ZBiQDjAAC1Ca9HdoLT2HEHPL4NFN6-ZnVw9vX3jAkPDI6NikUCWymWRyEDyBSKJTKI0qq3WNXqjW2rXaT16-SGi3hazgG22GiAA)?

Comment: Exactly. That's what I want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order for your example code to work you need declarations corresponding to each line in that example code.  Let's look at them:

---

```
const cArray = new CustomArray<number>(1,3,2,3);
```

For this to work you need a *value* named `CustomArray`, whose type is a [constructor ("newable") signature](https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/docs/types/callable.html#newable) which takes a variadic list of `T` values and produces a `CustomArray<T>` value.  You don't add this to the `CustomArray<T>` interface, but instead need to declare it as a named value like this:

```
declare const CustomArray: new <T>(...a: T[]) => CustomArray<T>;
```

---

```
cArray[0] = 2;
console.log(cArray[2]) // 2
```

For these to work you need the `CustomArray<T>` interface to have a numeric [index signature](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html#indexable-types) whose values are type `T`, like this:

```
    [n: number]: T;
```

---

```
for (const i of cArray) {
    console.log(i);
}
```

For this to work, you need the `CustomArray<T>` interface to be [iterable](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/iterators-and-generators.html#iterables), meaning it has a method named [`Symbol.iterator`](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/symbols.html#symboliterator) which returns an [`Iterator<T>`](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/v3.7.3/lib/lib.es2015.iterable.d.ts#L43-L48):

```
    [Symbol.iterator](): IterableIterator<T>;
```

---

Similar things need to be done for your `CustomMap` to work.  Overall, here's how I'd expect your declarations to look:

```
//iter.d.ts
interface CustomMap<U, V> {
    get(key: U): V | undefined;
    set(key: U, val: V): void;
    [Symbol.iterator](): IterableIterator<[U, V]>
}
declare const CustomMap: new <U, V>(...a: [U, V][]) => CustomMap<U, V>;

interface CustomArray<T> {
    length(): number;
    [n: number]: T;
    [Symbol.iterator](): IterableIterator<T>;
}
declare const CustomArray: new <T>(...a: T[]) => CustomArray<T>;
```

And then the following should compile (note the `cArray` and `cMap` variables need to have a proper declaration, like `const`):

```
//test.ts

const cArray = new CustomArray<number>(1, 3, 2, 3);
cArray[0] = 2;
console.log(cArray[2]) // 2
for (const i of cArray) {
    console.log(i);
}

const cMap = new CustomMap<string, string>(['1', 'a'], ['3', 'b'], ['2', 'ç'], ['4', 'd']);
for (const [k, v] of cMap) {
    console.log(k + ':' + v);
}
```

---

Okay, hope that helps; good luck!

[Link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#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-Ai2GHU6XWiWzIuA5NZ6UQtfT4UbrA0aTTJiABqCuKLOLxxhopAA)